# Vue global variable breaking build with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs2

I have the following:

*main.js*

```
Vue.prototype.$someVariable = Vue.observable([] as Array<SomeClass>);
```

*.vue file:*

```
console.log(this.$someVariable); //this gets a red squiggly from intellisense
```

This will not build because:

> Property '$someVariable' does not exist on type 'ComponentRenderProxy...

But it does, doesn't it? Can someone help me out here, what am I missing? I would be happy to provide more data if it will help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At the project root add a file name `some-variable.d.ts` with the following content :

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {

  interface Vue {
    $someVariable: <theType>
  }
}
```

Comment: I did this and I am still getting the error/intellisense problem

Comment: please restart the editor and the compilation